# Resolve multiple Promises returning merged data

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6, promise, ecmascript-5

I'm just a beginner with **JavaScript Promises**, although I have extensively used them in my life, with AJAX requests.

I am building a front-end application to run from SharePoint library and it requests user info from SharePoint API to customize the page content. To get all the information I want, I need to fetch 2 different URL, since one does not contain all the data I seek.

Besides, I am building a lib to facilitate the consumption of SharePoint API and I wish these 2 promises were resolved in a single one, with the results in both already merged in a single JSON `userData`. I know `Promise.all()` does something similar, however its result is an array with separate result, which does not meet the second part I want...

Also, keep in mind that I am building an application fully compatible with IE, so many resources like Asyn/Await are discarded.

So I wanted the function `getUser()` below already to return a promise with the merged object properties:

```
function getUser() {
    var userData1 = axios.get(url + '/web/CurrentUser');
    var userData2 = axios.get(url + '/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties');

    return Promise.all([userData1, userData2]);
}

var userDataAll;
getUser().then(function(values) {
    userDataAll = Object.assign({}, values[0].data, values[1].data);
});
```

Comment: Ok, so where's the issue exactly? You didn't ask anything, and didn't mention how the code fails. Are you asking how to turn the array into an object inside `getUser`?

Comment: If that is what you're asking, you can just add a `.then()`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/Lje73nuf/

Comment: I wanted all the promises and the merge to be resumed into a single `Promise`, with the result ready to use within `.then()`. The answer/solution has already been shared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it! I understood the way promises work and found the solution myself: all I needed is to encapsulate the steps into a new promise and call the `resolve()`callback once `Promise.all()` is resolved and the merge ended with the `Object.assign()`:

```
function getUser() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var userData1 = axios.get(url + '/web/CurrentUser');
        var userData2 = axios.get(url + '/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties');
        Promise
            .all([userData1, userData2])
            .then(function(results) {
                let userData = Object.assign({}, results[0].data, results[1].data);
                resolve(userData);
            })
            .catch(function(errors) {
                reject(errors);
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Yes, I'll do it!

Comment: That new Promise is not needed, like I showed in my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/Lje73nuf/

Comment: These is very similar to what I already had. I was no clear in my question, but I was wanting to have a function which returned a promise with both objects received from the fetching operation already merged. This answer I posted fit perfectly to what I wanted. But thank you for contributing...

Comment: Yes, but you don't need the `new Promise()` wrapper; instead simply `var userData1 = ...; var userData2 = ...; return Promise.all([userData1, userData2]).then(results => Object.assign(results[0].data, results[1].data));`.